# Get a reference to the enclosing module in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you get a reference to the enclosing module in ruby?

```
module Foo
   @@variable=1

   def variable
      @@variable
   end

    class A
      def somemethod
         puts "variable=#{Foo.variable}" #<--this won't run, resolving Foo 
                                        # as the class instead of the module
      end
    end

    class Foo
        ... # doesn't matter what's here
    end
end
```

I ran into this question caused by naming confusion. While the names are easy enough to fix, I"m wondering what the "correct" way is to do this in ruby. If I try to run this it seems like ruby is trying to resolve Foo.variable as Foo::Foo.variable which of course fails. It seems like there should be a simple way in the language to refer to the outer module method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the outer module reference by adding the `::` prefix to `Foo`:

```ruby
::Foo.variable
```

In your example code:

```
module Foo
   @@variable=1

   def variable
      @@variable
   end

    class A
      def somemethod
         puts "variable=#{::Foo.variable}"
      end
    end

    class Foo
        ... # doesn't matter what's here
    end
end
```

Comment: When I try it I get:
`
    foo.rb:14:in `somemethod': undefined method `variable' for Foo:Module (NoMethodError)
        from foo.rb:31:in `<main>'
`

Comment: Try to declare the method variable like this: `def self.variable`